# Is this unexpected upvote reversal evidence of a bug or just serial upvote reversal?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, up-votes

Yesterday my reputation was reduced for an upvote reverse on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235906/how-do-i-fix-this-bad-bending-in-my-minecraft-arm/237158#237158) as witnessed by this summary:

[image: -10 charge on question]

Earlier, the upvote reversal showed in the question timeline and the points were deducted from my reputation. But now it's not showing in the question timeline yet the deduction still stands:

[image: vote reversal not showing on time line]

I believe this is a bug, but I would appreciate clarification if it's not. I don't see how the upvote could be reversed so long after the last edit to the question, because I thought upvotes were locked after a short period of time.

I also don't understand why the reversal isn't in the timeline, but I suppose that's by-design -- in which case, I'd appreciate a clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/1485065), which has the situation as it was last Sunday morning, your answer received one upvote on September 3rd.

[image]

It's not visible in the timeline but it *is* still visible in your [reputation history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/42221/marty-fouts?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2):

[image]

because it's cancelled out by today's unupvote. It might be confusing but I guess it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I've clarified my question since your answer.  I can see that removing the two entries from the timeline could be bydesign, but that still leaves me wondering how the upvote was reversed so long after the last edit to the answer.

Comment: @MartyFouts The time since the edit isn't important - only that the edit ever happened. So, if I vote today and you edit in 10 minutes... I can change my vote 10 years from now if the post still isn't deleted.

Comment: @Catija  Thanks.  That's the part I was unclear on.